# How to add value substring inside decimal in PHP

Tags: php, substring

I have a number like this

```
"0.321527778"
```

I want make some substring from my value in top and then for the substring result I want input that number into the my decimal number, how can I do? *(for substring I cut from 2 last digits from decimal number)*

for the expetation result will be like this :

```
"0.321527777777778"
```

code :

```
<?php

  $number = "0.321527778";

  $substring = substr($number, -2, -1);

  print_r($number . ' ' . $substring);

?>
```

result :

```
0.321527778 7
```

***If my explanation is incomprehensible, I apologize, and you can ask me again, Thank You***

Comment: you cut 7 from your number, where you want to insert 7 and how many times?? give an example in the way you want to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the substrings before and after the part that you want to insert multiple times. Then concatenate everything without putting spaces between them.

```
$number = "0.321527778";
$beginning = substr($number, 0, -2);
$end = substr($number, -1);
$substring = substr($number, -2, -1);
$result = $beginning . str_repeat($substring, 6) . $end;
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is a good idea, but when I want to make this method I only remember normal iterations like `while` ,  `do-while` , or  `for` , actually `str_repeat` can be used in this problem, Thank you @Barmar

Comment: Are you saying you're not allowed to use `str_repeat` and you have to your own loop to do it?

Comment: It should be a simple loop for you to write, I leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: No, I'm not saying  cannot use `str_repeat`, but in my head just remembered about normal looping, but your answer is way to open my logic, Thanks